# Android Java code to mimic a 2 Keystroke sequence (to perform a device screenshot)

Tags: android, screenshot, surfaceview, android-intent, keystrokes

I have been trying to get a bitmap screenshot of a SurfaceView for days but the more I look into it, there doesn't seem to be a solution at present for Android OS 2.3.4 based OSs my device from HTC.

So on to Plan B, where I just found out another blog: "On my HTC Evo 3d, all I have to do is hold the power button for 1-2 sec and then hit the home button and it takes a screen shot. No app required."  Turns out this works perfectly on my tablet.

I also know from digging around there are these intents: android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF & android.intent.category.HOME

(So I tried a bunch of code experiments to try to mimic the 2-key combo in code to get a screenshot in this brute force manor.  Unfortunately without success).

So my ? -- Does anyone have any insights into a method to invoke this 'screenshot sequence' for my HTC device from java code?  (Presume I need to fool the OS into thinking I am holding down the power key AND tap the Home key, simultaneously)...

More: Here is a snip of the code I am attempting:

Button click for test... ...

```
  Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
      inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER);
      Instrumentation inst2 = new Instrumentation();
      inst2.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);
    } // run
  }; // thread t
```

Doesnt work as the inst.sendKeyDownUpSync is wrong as I need a sendKeyDown (& hold) behavior or its equivel

Many thanks for any advise.  If I do get this working, I will post the solution here.  Cheers GH

PS;  I presume there is some custom intent under the hood doing this?  Is there a system log somewhere to trey to peek at the call tree to find out what it is ?

EDIT (MORE)... 9/24/11

More. Still not working but I am heading down this path & think it is closer...

// Attempt to SIMULATE A Long press (DOWN) + HOME to tell the HTC to invoke the 'Screenshot' command (WARNING: HTC Tablet specific behavior!)

```
        Thread tt = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
          final KeyEvent dapowerkey = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER); 

          Handler onesecondhandler = new Handler(); 
          onesecondhandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { 
              // fpr about 1 second send power down keystrokes (DOWN ONLY)
              while (true) { dispatchKeyEvent(dapowerkey); }
            }  // we are done running on the timer past time point
          }, 750);  // 3/4 second key press
          // send the HOME keystroke 
          Instrumentation inst1 = new Instrumentation();
          inst1.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);        
        } // outer thread run tp mpt block the GUI
      }; // outer thread t
      tt.start(); 
      ...
```

Also thought if I can send the right intent directly to the proper place on the device that I might be able to kick off a screen capture function directly (which is what I *really* want.  Through some log examinations (when you Long-Power + Home click on HTC) a program called 'com.htc.mysketcher' (FlashActivity) is being called...

Again, if I figure this out then I will post to the group... Cheers GH